# How do I access "My Favorites" in Android App?

Tags: support, favorite-tag, android-app

For some reason I can't find my starred posts in Mi Yodea (mobile Android App).

If someone can please give me some insight on how to find it, that would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: On iOS it is found under a ‘more’ section

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Can you please post a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Manually input `infavorites:mine` into the search bar.**

Currently, there is no native button to access your favorites; the functionality exists, but only if you manually put `infavorites:mine` into the search box.

To quote the official answer from Meta.SE:

> Currently this is really difficult to do in app, it definitely needs to be done in a better way. For now, you can search `infavorites:mine` on a site to get your favorites, but this obviously can be done better. - [Kasra Rahjerdi - A: Favorite questions in the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229697/294691)

Kasra was for around years the only developer on the Android app, but he has since left the company. The apps haven't seen any new development in a while, so I doubt that this will change any time soon.